# Use of unassigned local variable in Graphics Class

Tags: c#, emgucv

I get an error in the "gr.DrawLine()" part in my code. The error it gives me is this:

> Use of unassigned local variable in 'gr'

I want to create a red border in my rectangle for ROI in EmguCV. This is my code:

```
public static Mat crop_roi(Mat input_img)
        {
            Image<Gray, byte> img = input_img.ToImage<Gray, byte>();
            double w = input_img.Width;
            double h = input_img.Height;

            Rectangle r = new Rectangle((int)(100 * 0.2), (int)(100 * 0.4), (int)(w * 0.6), (int)(h * 0.6));

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Red);
            Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            gr.DrawRectangle(p, r.X, r.Bottom - 1, r.X, r.Y);

            Image<Gray, byte> output = img.Copy(r);

            return output.Mat;
        }
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that this is error is occurring is that your **`Graphics` object, `gr`, is never assigned a value**, hence the issue:

> Use of unassigned local variable in 'gr'

A simple example of how you can fix this is by doing the following:

```
//To get it from a PaintEvent
Graphics gr = System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs.Graphics;
```

**OR**

```
//To get it from the drawing surface
Graphics gr = this.CreateGraphics();
```

To create the `Graphics` object from an Image such as a Bitmap, you can do:

```
//Getting it from a Bitmap.
Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);
```

**For more information** on creating a `Graphics` object in C#, you can check out [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-graphics-objects-for-drawing#creating-a-graphics-object) documentation.

Comment: So I need to have a form for this? But I don't have a form. this is a console application.

Comment: I used your suggestion but the "Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(img);" is giving me an error of: Cannot convert from 'Emgu.CV.Image.Structure.Gray, byte> to System.Drawing.Image" Some more help please.

Comment: @Ibanez1408, if my updated answer helped you or if you still have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Do you know if `img` is of the type `Bitmap`? You can also check out [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-graphics-objects-for-drawing#creating-a-graphics-object) on creating a `Graphics` object.

Comment: I gues I have to convert the Image<Gray, byte> image to a bitmap for this to work. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.